# How a lambda expression maps into a functional interface?

Tags: java, lambda, functional-programming, java-8, java-stream

Let's look at the below code.

```
    List<String> names = Arrays.asList("Adam", "Brian", "Supun");
    List<Integer> lengths = names.stream()
                                 .map(name -> name.length())
                                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

And simply then will look at the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) for `streams.map`. There the signature for `map` method appears like this.

```
<R> Stream<R> map(Function<? super T,? extends R> mapper)
```

Can somebody please explain how JVM maps the lambda expression we gave (`name -> name.length()`) in terms of `Function<? super T,? extends R> mapper`?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? You shouldn't ever need to create local variables of the Stream type. Are you looking for `names.stream().map(...).collect(Collectors.toList())` ? Also, don't use the raw List type.

Comment: @Michael actually I needed the viewers to focus on the lambda expression part. SO I didn't add the latter additions you have mentioned. This is just to understand the mapping of lambda into a functional interface. Nothing else. :))

Comment: @Michael got your point. Thank You. :)) Hope I have corrected the code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A `Function` is something that takes `X` and returns `Y`.

```
 ? super T     == String
 ? extends R   == Integer
```

basically with `name -> name.length()` you are implementing the `@FunctionlInterface Function<T,R>` with overriding the single abstract method `R apply(T t)`.

You can also shorten that with a method reference :

```
Stream<Integer> lengths = names.stream().map(String::length);
```

Answer (score 2):

Check `apply` method from `Function`:

```
R apply(T t);
```

`? extends R` is return type,  `? super T` is taken type

As `Function` class has only one non-default `public` method, it can map your lambda to `Function` instance